# How to do the sorting of the data in an HTML/D3 code

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

My question is how to do the sorting of the data in an HTML/D3 code shown below.
I code in Python, and HTML/CSS are new to me. I have the following code, I am preparing the data inside, how can I sort this data. 
 Without considering the and not taking care of the labels. I want to just sort the data. How can I accomplish the same. Many thanks. I am learning this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Sorting visual elements</title>
         <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 600;
            var h = 250;

            var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                            11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

            var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                            .rangeRound([0, w])
                            .paddingInner(0.05);

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
                            .range([0, h]);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Create bars
            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", (d,i) => xScale(i) )
               .attr("y", d => h - yScale(d) )
               .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
               .attr("height", d => yScale(d) )
               .attr("fill", d => "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")" )

               .on("mouseover", function() {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .attr("fill", "orange");
               })
               .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                   d3.select(this)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(250)
                        .attr("fill", "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")")
               })
               .on("click", () => sortBars() );

            //Create labels
            svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(d => d)
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
               .attr("y", d => h - yScale(d) + 14 )
               .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
               .attr("font-size", "11px")
               .attr("fill", "white");

            //Define sort function
            var sortBars = function() {

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a, b) )
                   .transition()
                   .duration(1000)
                   .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i) );
                    };          

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `dataset.sort((a, b) => a - b)`. Here is the code with that change: https://jsfiddle.net/bv0jauf1/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thank you Gerardo, can you help me in other stuffs too, there are other things, little tweaks.

Comment: please also add, it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: this is a duplicate, which I already closed as such (here at Stack Overflow duplicated questions should not be answered, just closed with the adequate target, so OP can read them and find the correct answer). Also, if you have another problems to fix please post them as new questions.

Comment: Okay, I will add my comment here, to take you on a new question and many thanks Gerardo

Comment: In the file svg-tooltip.html, how can I modify the code such
that on mouse out the values of the bars remain there, but they are white in
color.

Comment: It is not allowing me, asking me to wait for 90 minutes. I have full question ready. I will post it.

Comment: I think I need to wait 30 mins

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571316/change-the-colours-of-the-bars-at-mouseout-in-svg-tooltip-html

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571316/change-the-colours-of-the-bars-at-mouseout-in-svg-tooltip-html