# Change the colours of the bars at mouseout in svg-tooltip.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

My question is based on a little modification in the code shown below. I code in Python, and HTML/CSS are new to me. I have the following code.

In the code below , modify the code such that on mouse out the values of the bars remain there, but they are white in color.
How can I accomplish the same. Many thanks. I am learning this.

```js
//Width and height
var w = 600;
var h = 250;

var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
  11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25
];

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
  .rangeRound([0, w])
  .paddingInner(0.05);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
  .range([0, h]);

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

//Create bars
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr("y", d => h - yScale(d))
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", d => yScale(d))
  .attr("fill", d => "rgb(100, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {

    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + 14;

    //Create the tooltip label
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("id", "tooltip")
      .attr("x", xPosition)
      .attr("y", yPosition)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .text(d);
  })
  .on("mouseout", () => d3.select("#tooltip").remove());
//Remove the tooltip
```

```css
rect:hover {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the bars remain there`?

Comment: that means, only color has to be changed, I think, I got the wrong file, is this original svg-toottip file.

Comment: I still don't understand. When you hover out of the elements containing the tooltips you want the white texted color of the buttons hovered to change? And I don't know if it's the original file, you tell me?

Comment: modify the code such
that on mouseout the values of the bars remain there, but they are white in
color.

Comment: Please check your question and run the code you shared, there are absolutely no white bars. Kindly update your question to add any relevant information, as as it is it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: okay, I will do it

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, I have edited the question.

Comment: *"In the code below , modify the code such that"*... is that a homework?

Comment: Not homework, my tasks, I am learning D3 and HTML/JS.  I am Python and R developer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, Can you guide me please

Comment: @Shivam_hbti fair enough, I voted to reopen. Also, as a suggestion, please don't ask the help of any specific user. This is an open community, who wants to write an answer will provide one.

Comment: I see, okay. I understand you. Thanks

Comment: @GerardoFurtado you could tho ask for help of a specific user so the user would notice the question. It's up to him tho to answer or not, that's what I think.

Comment: I am not sure, if this question can be answered. The files was wrong yesterday, I got it today